# Rail Baltica, Warsaw-Kaunas segment

Tags: trains, poland, lithuania

I can't understand the status of [Rail Baltica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_Baltica) on the "Warsaw-Kaunas" segment. In the  past, it was several times announced "we are testing, open soon".

What is the status right now? Are they going to open it in 2019?

P.S. I am interested in high-speed passenger trains.

Comment: From looking at the http://www.railbaltica.org/ site, it looks like they are currently (12/2018) in the planning and bidding phases. If that's the case, it certainly won't be open in 2019, but the actual status is a little hard to determine.

Comment: https://www.baltictimes.com/eur_400_200_to_be_spent_on_communications_strategy__pr_services_for_rail_baltica/  this is out of control. EU is going to buncrupt.

Answer (score 6):

Since 11th of December 2022 the train connection is working.
You can find more information and tickets here:
https://ltglink.lt/en/vilnius-warsaw-krakow-vilnius

The journey lasts around 8 hours from Vilnius to Warsawa.

Comment: Note that this is not Rail Baltica, which is planned to take around half the time, but rather just a new line added in the latest timetable. Railway connections between Warsaw and Vilnius were available earlier as well, but for most of 2022 they were only on weekends.

Answer (score 3):

It was always a political game. Poland used to have some unresolved issues with Lithuania (like the status of polish minority there). Lack of good train connections and  highways was used as a way of pressure by Polish government on Lithuanians.

From the economical point of view, do not expect a high-speed passenger train. Eastern Poland and Baltics are not so dense populated to justify such a big investment.

Honestly speaking, I wish an old 19th-century, shortest connection Warsaw - Hrodno - Vilnus could be reactivated. But as long as it crosses Belarus (which is not a EU member) this seems impossible.

Comment: You mean Belarus is *not* an EU member, right?  (Also, welcome to Travel StackExchange!)

Comment: According to the man in seat 61 https://www.seat61.com/warsaw-to-vilnius-by-train.htm there is a service although not especially direct or convenient and it does not pass through Belarus.

Comment: That's a local disel train Białystok - Trakiszki (station at Lithuanian border, where you can change to Kaunas/Vilnus). Operates only on weekends, slower than a bus, because it follows longer route.